# Can you open programs to the notification tray (i.e. not maximised) and close programs through a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am running a Ninite.exe in my startup folder so that the programs I have that are on Ninite are kept up to date which seems to work really well. However, I am encountering two problems with this:

1) A while ago, Glary Utilities stopped updating because Ninte said the program was running. I've somewhat got around this by not having Glary launch at startup anymore, but instead launching through a batch file that has a delay at the start. So Ninite can update Glary before Glary launches. The problem with this, is that the Glary window shows up every time it launches. If I use the option within Glary itself to start on Windows startup,  it launches minimised to the notification tray. Is there any parameters I can use in my batch file to make sure that Glary launches minimised to the notification tray?

2) Following on from this, I would like to know if there are any parameters for closing a window? I would like to use this to close the Ninite window when it has finished updating my programs.

TL;DR Are there any parameters in batch files to only open a program minimised to the notification tray and/or close a window.

Comment: Set Glary to automatic startup. Run msconfig. Check what the command is. Oh, with Windows 10 msconfig now directs you over to Task Manager. And hey, it doesn't show the commands. :( And neither does the listing in the W10 settings panel. But msinfo32 does show you.

Comment: Oh, one can't simply copy from the listing in `msinfo32`. So if you want that you'll probably have to inspect the registry, e.g. via `regedit`. Startup commands will probably reside in one of the [registry "run" keys](https://www.enigmasoftware.com/what-are-run-keys-registry/).

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. Try `help start`, specifically the /MIN option. Killing a running program is another problem. You should only ask one question at a time. That's one reason you're collecting down-votes on this question.

Comment: 1. Only if glary supports it, 2. Use `taskkill`

Answer (score 0):

I once made a batch file to open steam games and I used `start`

```
:START_CHOICE
echo [1] PUBG
echo [2] EXIT
if %input%==1 goto CHOICE_1 if NOT goto START_CHOICE
if %input%==2 goto CHOICE_2 if NOT goto START_CHOICE
:CHOICE_1
:CONFIRM2
echo Enter COMPUTER PASSWORD
set input2=
set /p input2=
If /I "%input2%"=="4862" goto PLAY2
echo Invalid password.
echo --------------------------
goto CONFIRM2
:PLAY2
echo Proceeding to PUBG!
timeout /t 3 /nobreak
start steam://rungameid/578080
EXIT
:CHOICE_2
EXIT
```

You'll have to do `start --YourFileNameOrShortcut--` Just don't use --
Also to minimize it use `EXIT`

Comment: Tell me if this helps @missing string